# How to cut first column (variable length) of a string in shell

Tags: linux, shell

How to cut first column (variable length) of a string in shell ?

ex of string :

23006   help.txt

I need 23006 as output

Answer (score 61):

Many ways:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 <filename # If field separator is space
cut -f1 <filename  # If field separator is tab
cut -d' ' -f1 <filename | cut -f1  # If field separator is space OR tab
awk '{print $1}' filename
while read x _ ; do echo $x ; done < filename
```

Comment: Somehow, with the `cut` option, when I piped in `ps` output, the only entries in the displayed results were the ones with the first column (as meant by the OP) being of length 5 and the ones with length 3 or 4 were not. There was a blank area before the displayed output, I guess this space is equal in line numbers (term height) as the above mentioned lines, with hidden 3 / 4 char wide first column entry. The `awk` way worked fine.

Comment: `ps` gives a formatted output. (like `printf %5d` would give.) So, when `cut` is using `space` as the delimiter, it sees the leading space (for smaller PID numbers) as delimiters. Hence it prints everything before the first space (which is nothing in that case.)

Answer (score 12):

```
cut -d " " -f1 test.txt
```

where test.txt contains your input line

Answer (score 6):

This one works for me

```
cut -d' ' -f2-
```